# Notice: Array to string conversion ERROR

Tags: php, arrays

I have a script which find all possible combinations of a multidimensional array:

I'm getting this error:

```
<?php
    $traits = array
    (
        array('Happy', 'Sad', 'Angry', 'Hopeful'),
        array('Outgoing', 'Introverted'),
        array('Tall', 'Short', 'Medium'),
        array('Handsome', 'Plain', 'Ugly')
    );

    $i = 0;
    if ($i >= count($traits))
        echo "<BR>\n";
    else
    {
        foreach ($traits[$i] as $trait)
        {
            foreach($traits as $item)
            {
                echo '<BR>'.$trait, $item, $i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

where did I go wrong?

this is the original code:

```
<?php
    function showCombinations($string, $traits, $i)
    {
        if ($i >= count($traits))
            echo trim($string) . "\n";
        else
        {
            foreach ($traits[$i] as $trait)
                showCombinations("$string $trait", $traits, $i + 1);
        }
    }

    $traits = array
    (
        array('Happy', 'Sad', 'Angry', 'Hopeful'),
        array('Outgoing', 'Introverted'),
        array('Tall', 'Short', 'Medium'),
        array('Handsome', 'Plain', 'Ugly')
    );

    showCombinations('', $traits, 0);
?>
```

So I remove the function cause I don't want to used a function.

expected output from the 1st code:

```
Happy Outgoing Tall Handsome
Happy Outgoing Tall Plain
Happy Outgoing Tall Ugly
Happy Outgoing Short Handsome
Happy Outgoing Short Plain
Happy Outgoing Short Ugly
Happy Outgoing Medium Handsome
Happy Outgoing Medium Plain
Happy Outgoing Medium Ugly
Happy Introverted Tall Handsome
Happy Introverted Tall Plain
Happy Introverted Tall Ugly
Happy Introverted Short Handsome
Happy Introverted Short Plain
Happy Introverted Short Ugly
Happy Introverted Medium Handsome
Happy Introverted Medium Plain
Happy Introverted Medium Ugly
Sad Outgoing Tall Handsome
Sad Outgoing Tall Plain
Sad Outgoing Tall Ugly
Sad Outgoing Short Handsome
Sad Outgoing Short Plain
Sad Outgoing Short Ugly
Sad Outgoing Medium Handsome
Sad Outgoing Medium Plain
Sad Outgoing Medium Ugly
Sad Introverted Tall Handsome
Sad Introverted Tall Plain
Sad Introverted Tall Ugly
Sad Introverted Short Handsome
Sad Introverted Short Plain
Sad Introverted Short Ugly
Sad Introverted Medium Handsome
Sad Introverted Medium Plain
Sad Introverted Medium Ugly
Angry Outgoing Tall Handsome
Angry Outgoing Tall Plain
Angry Outgoing Tall Ugly
Angry Outgoing Short Handsome
Angry Outgoing Short Plain
Angry Outgoing Short Ugly
Angry Outgoing Medium Handsome
Angry Outgoing Medium Plain
Angry Outgoing Medium Ugly
Angry Introverted Tall Handsome
Angry Introverted Tall Plain
Angry Introverted Tall Ugly
Angry Introverted Short Handsome
Angry Introverted Short Plain
Angry Introverted Short Ugly
Angry Introverted Medium Handsome
Angry Introverted Medium Plain
Angry Introverted Medium Ugly
Hopeful Outgoing Tall Handsome
Hopeful Outgoing Tall Plain
Hopeful Outgoing Tall Ugly
Hopeful Outgoing Short Handsome
Hopeful Outgoing Short Plain
Hopeful Outgoing Short Ugly
Hopeful Outgoing Medium Handsome
Hopeful Outgoing Medium Plain
Hopeful Outgoing Medium Ugly
Hopeful Introverted Tall Handsome
Hopeful Introverted Tall Plain
Hopeful Introverted Tall Ugly
Hopeful Introverted Short Handsome
Hopeful Introverted Short Plain
Hopeful Introverted Short Ugly
Hopeful Introverted Medium Handsome
Hopeful Introverted Medium Plain
Hopeful Introverted Medium Ugly
```

Comment: You may get better answers if you state what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Upvoted question and voted to reopen after the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change:

```
foreach ($traits[$i] as $trait)
```

To:

```
foreach ($traits as $trait)
```

Then realize that `$trait` is still an array. So instead of

```
echo '<BR>'.$trait, $test, $i + 1;
```

You want to still loop through *that* array:

```
foreach($trait AS $value)
```

Now you can echo out your `$value`

```
foreach ($traits as $trait) {
    foreach($trait AS $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

**Update**: Between comments below and several question updates, it became clear what the desired output actually was. Final solution is here: http://3v4l.org/X3i3p

Comment: Why should he? `$traits` is a 2-dimensional array, but `$traits` is not. So changing this would still return the previous error.

Comment: @Darline you still have `echo '<BR>'.$trait` in your code. `$trait` is an array, you can't just echo it.

Comment: @Darline look at my final `foreach` loop. That will let you echo out every individual value. What else do you need it to do?

Comment: @jszobody: Why do you think I'm the one who downvoted? (I'm not). Blindly accusing someone of downvoting isn't productive/helpful.

Comment: @AmalMurali Ok my bad. I got two downvotes the same time you commented. Wrongly assumed.

Comment: @Darline Are you trying to spit out the values comma separated? With a numeric index on each line? Can you show what the actual HTML output should look like?

Comment: @Darline show me the _HTML_ output that you want. The actual, final, output. It will be real easy to solve this for you if we know what your end goal is.

Comment: @Darline: Updating the question a thousand times with no explanation doesn't help. Please **describe** what you're trying to do, the errors (if any) that you're getting, and the expected output.

Comment: @Darline Oh... now I see. I ran the original function code you provided. It's a recursive function, and to get the output you want it _needs_ to be recursive. Why in the world are you trying to get rid of a perfectly good function? It seems to work quite well.

Comment: @Darline What does "run manually" mean? You need a recursive function to do this.

Comment: @Darline explain yourself. why can't you use a function?

Comment: @Darline Wow, ok. This is the first you've actually said what you wanted! You would have gotten an answer a lot sooner (and probably not been put on hold) if you had just said that up front. One sec.

Comment: @Darline Ok see here: http://3v4l.org/poTS8 The function now returns a string rather than echoing. And you can easily convert that string to an array if needed.

Comment: @Darline. I don't think you've heard me. _YOU NEED A FUNCTION_ to do this. It has to be recursive.

Comment: @Darline sure: http://3v4l.org/X3i3p

Comment: @Darline what string? All you have to do is `$combinations = getCombinations($traits);` and you have your array. What's the problem?

Comment: @Darline explain why?

Comment: @Darline no it does not print null values. and it is needed. you have your solution, doing _exactly_ what you asked it to do.

Comment: @jszobody I see. thank you again thanks so much and I'm sorry for being :( so newbie :( thanks alot and take care

Comment: @jszobody can delete all the comment here? thank you